# How to publish data when receive expect mesage in MQTT paho python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mqtt, paho

Setup MQTT broker and Database MySQL for IoT testing.

I want to implement client to subscribe MQTT topic, if it receive exactly message from MQTT broker (such as "read") it will read database and publish data to broker.

Now, my python client can receive message and check message. It also connect MySQL database to read data. But I don't know how to publish this data to MQTT broker.

Here is my code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient
import time
import MySQLdb

#connect database
db_local = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root123","mqtt")

def read_action():
  with db_local:
    cur = db_local.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `hengio_action` WHERE username ='lam'")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
      command = row['command']
    return command

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
 if rc == 0:
   print("Connected to broker")
   global Connected                #Use global variable
   Connected = True                #Signal connection 
 else:
   print("Connection failed")

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
 print "Message received: "  + message.payload
 if(message.payload=="read"):
    command = read_action()
    print command

Connected = False   #global variable for the state of the connection
broker_address= "MQTT broker IP"  #Broker address
port = 1883                         #Broker port
keepalive = 0                       #always listen
user = "lam"                    #Connection username
password = "lam"            #Connection password
client = mqttClient.Client("Python")               #create new instance
client.username_pw_set(user, password=password)    #set username and password
client.on_connect= on_connect                      #attach function to callback
client.on_message= on_message                      #attach function to callback
client.connect(broker_address, port=port,keepalive=keepalive)             #connect to broker 
client.loop_start()        #start the loop
while Connected != True:    #Wait for connection
    time.sleep(0.1)
client.subscribe("LAM_TEST_ANDROID")
try:
  while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "exiting"
    client.disconnect()
    client.loop_stop()
```

Comment: Have you read the paho python doc (https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#publishing)?

Comment: Also `keepalive` really should not be 0

Comment: But I want client always ready receive message. If I dont set keepalive = 0, it will disconnect.

Comment: No it will not, keepalive is how long to wait if there are no messages before the broker will check if the client is still alive.

Comment: Yes, I can publish message now. About keepalive  different 0, you are right, but suppose, I set keepalive = 60s, after 60s, when I want to sub/pub, it must created connect again, quiet time consuming. Speed decrease. How do I do?

Comment: @nistelrooy41001662 I don't think so. keepalive is used by the broker to send a ping message to the client to verify if it is still connected. You can use the existing client connection to pub/sub message no matter what your keepalive value is.